# Plot point on graph via user input

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am really trying to do something simple here, but struggling a lot.

I am trying to get users to input points onto a graph that will update in real time.

Here's the scenario.

My graph will be projected in an exhibition, and then when a user inputs how long it take them to get to work, it then shows that point on the graph.

As more users input their data I will eventually have generated a graph that shows all the inputs relative to each other.

Here is what I ended up doing that worked really well!

```
from pylab import *

def click(event):
   """If the left mouse button is pressed: draw a little square. """
   tb = get_current_fig_manager().toolbar
   if event.button==1 and event.inaxes and tb.mode == '':
       x,y = event.xdata,event.ydata
       plot([x],[y],'rs')
       draw()

plt.title('How long does it take you to get to work?\nClick the spot.')
plt.xlabel('Kms')
plt.ylabel('Hours')
plt.legend()

plot((arange(100)/18))
gca().set_autoscale_on(False)
connect('button_press_event',click)
annotate('Line Of Disadvantage', xy=(20, 1), xytext=(7, 3),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))
annotate('Most Disadvantaged',xy=(20, 1), xytext=(5, 5)),
annotate('Least Disadvantaged',xy=(20, 1), xytext=(70, 1)),

show()
```

Comment: Wouldn't a histogram or bar chart be a better way to represent that kind of data? Rather than plotting random numbers on the y-axis to spread them out.

Comment: @DavidG I have started using a bar graph. Please help me. Have a look at the updated code above.

Comment: Are you having the python code itself have the user input a value and then update the bar plot? Also is your text file just there to save the inputs?

Comment: Hi @DavidG - see above for the final solution.

Comment: That's a great way of representing the data you will get. I didn't even think of doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a little somthing. It will still require some work, but this should give you a good starting point

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def replot(distance_list, duration_list):
    # this function will produce the desired output chart (also used to reload the chart after data has been added)

    # close all older plots
    plt.close('all')

    plt.plot(distance_list, duration_list, 'ro')

    # refer to matplotlib documentation to learn how to format your chart.
    # I suggest, you add a chart title, axis legends etc.
    # you can also change the size and color of dots

    plt.xlabel('x-axis')
    plt.ylabel('y-axis')
    plt.title('Title')

    # maximise the plot window and show it:
    figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    figManager.window.showMaximized()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


def user_interaction():
    # this function defines/loads the information to be displayed
    # it asks for user input 
    # it stores the new user input and triggers the chart to be refreshed

    # define lists with information
    distance_list = [1,2,3,4]

    duration_list = [1,4,9,16]

    # I suggest to manipulate the script in the followig way:
    # you want to preserve the infomration that users input. Instead of defining the lists above, you want to load the "previous" information:
    # there are many ways of storing and loading information. You could use .csv, .txt files or you could save a dict in json format....

    # ask for user input
    new_distance = float(raw_input("How far away is your work, in km? "))
    new_duration = float(raw_input("How long does it take you to get there, in min? "))

    # append user input to existing list
    distance_list.append(new_distance)
    duration_list.append(new_duration)

    # save the appended lists
    # I suggest you write the user information to file. That way, they can be re-loaded when the next user enters data. The data will also survive computer shut-dwon etc.


    # now, send the two lists to a plotting function
    replot( distance_list, duration_list )


if __name__=='__main__':

    user_interaction()
```

You will need to find a way of 'starting the script again'. When the next user comes along, the script needs to aks him the same questions again. Maybe others can help with that.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'showMaximized'

Comment: Also, there is no graph that pops up when I run the module. Using Python3.4 on Rasbpian.

Comment: Ok, this is where I am now. Working somewhat. @rde See original post for updated code and issues.

Comment: @LukeVenter, can you point out what exactly you are stuck with? Since you are on python 3 and I am using 2.7, some commands may not work (e.g. the figManager/fullscreen).

Comment: See above to what I eventually did that worked out for me quite well. @rde

Comment: Is there any way I can thank you for your help, @rde?